# Make a tcolorbox table, using tabularx, fit the \linewidth

Tags: tables, tcolorbox, multirow, resize, xtable

I have a pretty formatted table with tcolorbox, which uses tabularx under the hood. But, I don't know how I would configure it, as is possible with tabularx, to make the table fit the linewidth - without leaving a blankspace inside the table.

One solution I would be looking forward to have would, for an example, stretch automatically one of the cells to make it occupy the total space (like what my goal-table does with the "Esteira Transportadora" cell).

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, article]{abntex2}

%%%%%%%%%%%% ----------- PACOTES/PACKAGES ----------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Special Tables // Tabelas especiais
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor} %% Definição de cores
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}     %%Mudar ambientes de blocos
%multi-row

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>\arraybackslash\multirow{2}{*}{X}}% see tabularx
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
  colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!30!white,
  coltitle=black,center title,sharp corners, drop fuzzy shadow=black!30!white}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}]
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Primeira coluna
  \hline
  \cellcolor{orange!30} &
  \cellcolor{Lavender!70} &
  \cellcolor{white} &
  \cellcolor{Lavender!70} &
  Setor  &   Planta & Patrimônio \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%% Primeira coluna
  \cline{5-7}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Segunda coluna
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{orange!30}42.} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{Lavender!70} \textbf{Máquina}}&
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{white} \textbf{Esteira Transportadora}}&
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{Lavender!70} \textbf{Localização}}&
  53,8\%  &
  &
  Não identificado
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Segunda coluna
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I'm reproducing this table:
[image]

Currently looking like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around with the configurations on tcolorbox and did this:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft}X}% see tabularx
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
  colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!30!white,
  coltitle=black,center title,sharp corners, drop fuzzy shadow=black!30!white}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l|c|X|c|c|c|c|}]
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Primeira coluna
  \hline
  \cellcolor{orange!30} &
  \cellcolor{Lavender!70} &
  \cellcolor{white} &
  \cellcolor{Lavender!70} &
  Setor  &   Planta & Patrimônio \\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%% Primeira coluna
  \cline{5-7}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Segunda coluna
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{orange!30}42.} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{Lavender!70} \textbf{Máquina}}&
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{white} \textbf{Esteira Transportadora}}&
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{Lavender!70} \textbf{Localização}}&
  53,8\%  &
  &
  Não identificado
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Segunda coluna
\end{tcolorbox}
```

It worked like this, although I don't understand why it wasn't working then. Or why is it working now. But, I accept it.

Comment: `tabularx` isn't useful if you only use`l` and `c` columns (or even `r` or `p{}`). You need at least one `X`-type column to fill up the whole linewidth.

Comment: You also do not have to define a newcolumntype. X will work just fine.